# To Cloudmin GPL for Xen support CentOS Version?

Tags: centos, xen

I have decided to install Cloudmin GPL for XEN in CentOS Server with 64 bit and my server configuration is Hard Disk : 4TB latest Xeon processor. The Scripts download from the URL :

http://cloudmin.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/cloudmin-gpl-redhat-install.sh

Which version can support for this.

Note: The CentOS 5.6 with 64 bit version does not support.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the script 
http://cloudmin.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/cloudmin-gpl-redhat-install.sh

it's working fine and also you need to configure few things,

yum install birdge-utils*

for more help : https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/cloudmin/virtualization/xen